# Error: cordova-plugin-googleplus - SignInResult is null

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, google-authentication, phonegap

I am working on Ionic 2 app. I am using [EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) for Google login.

It works good with my project with the following plugins involved:

```
[ ~/projects/ionic/grmobile ]$ ionic plugins list
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.6 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.4 "LocalNotification"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

But it fails with the same code, with following plugins:

```
[ ~/projects/ionic/grmobile ]$ ionic plugin list
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.7.4 "Badges"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.6 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.2 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.19 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.7.5 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.6 "SocialSharing"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.4 "LocalNotification"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

I will narrow down the exact plugin(s), which is causing the issue and update here.

My code is:

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login({}, function(successMsg) {
  console.log(successMsg);
}, function(errorMsg) {
  console.log(errorMsg);
});
```

With the 2nd set of plugins, The login always fails with the following message:

`SignInResult is null`

The instant the login function is called, error callback is invoked with the msg

`SignInResult is null`

. But in device, Google account creation popup is displayed and when I tap on my account, neither success callback nor failure callback is invoked.

I installed the plugin with following command

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was because I use `cordova-plugin-background-mode`.

if you are using `cordova-plugin-background-mode` too, than add the line below in your

config.xml project's file.

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Google Plus "SignInResult is null" error, yet showing user device google account popup behaviour. in my Ionic v1 app

In my case using Angular Material Library was causing the issue.

Turns out Angular Material has some known integration issues with Ionic link below:
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

This comes when the auth server is returning a NULL.

**Ensure that you have added your certificate fingerprints to the project**

If not, go to `\Users\{username}\.android` (on Windows)

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
```

This will show your certificate fingerprints. Copy the `SHA1` fingerprint and add it to your firebase project's settings (Select Project > Cog Icon > Project Settings)

This should solve the problem.